# geochart - how to add some information about the regions

Tags: google-visualization

I have this geochart:     https://jsfiddle.net/y2dkrpg1/
Is it possible to add some adition information (text) about each region (for example by clicking on the region)?

Thank you!

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State', 'NS'],
        ['Blagoevgrad', 17],
        ['Burgas', 15],
        ['Varna', 27],
        ['Veliko Tarnovo', 24],
        ['Vidin', 30],
        ['Vratsa', 35],
        ['Gabrovo', 30],
        ['Dobrich', 37],
        ['Kardzhali', 23],
        ['Kyustendil', 17],
        ['Lovech', 20],
        ['Montana', 49],
        ['Pazardjik', 31],
        ['Pernik', 26],
        ['Pleven', 24],
        ['Plovdiv', 28],
        ['Razgrad', 25],
        ['Ruse', 28],
        ['Silistra', 49],
        ['Sliven', 17],
        ['Smolyan', 25],
        ['Sofia', 28],
        ['Stara Zagora', 20],
        ['Targovishte', 30],
        ['Haskovo', 40],
        ['Shumen', 40],
        ['Yambol', 30],
          ['Pazardzhik', 31],
          ['Sofia-grad', 12],
      ]);
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      fractionDigits: 0,
      suffix: '%'
    });
formatter.format(data, 1);
      var options = {
        region: 'BG',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Write something in stead of 'Tadam' and the values.

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State', 'NEETs','TADAM'],
        ['Blagoevgrad', 17, 100],
        ['Burgas', 15, 100],
        ['Varna', 27, 6],
        ['Veliko Tarnovo', 24, 34],
        ['Vidin', 30, 324],
        ['Vratsa', 35, 234],
        ['Gabrovo', 30, 32423],
        ['Dobrich', 37, 5],
        ['Kardzhali', 23, 5],
        ['Kyustendil', 17, 5],
        ['Lovech', 20, 345],
        ['Montana', 49, 43534],
        ['Pazardjik', 31, 34534],
        ['Pernik', 26, 34534],
        ['Pleven', 24, 3443],
        ['Plovdiv', 28, 34],
        ['Razgrad', 25, 100],
        ['Ruse', 28, 10],
        ['Silistra', 49, 1],
        ['Sliven', 17, 2],
        ['Smolyan', 25, 3],
        ['Sofia', 28, 4],
        ['Stara Zagora', 20, 5],
        ['Targovishte', 30, 6],
        ['Haskovo', 40, 7],
        ['Shumen', 40, 8],
        ['Yambol', 30, 9],
        ['Pazardzhik', 31, 10],
        ['Sofia-grad', 12, 11],
      ]);
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      fractionDigits: 0,
      suffix: '%'
    });
formatter.format(data, 1);
      var options = {
        region: 'BG',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y2dkrpg1/